# Not able to display the user's name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a rails application, where I have two models, user and team. team should have a captain_id which is actually a user_id, implemented through a has one association. Now my problem is that when I am creating a team, I am not able to display the captain's name in the show page of the team.

This is my model definition:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
    has_one   :captain, class_name: 'User' , foreign_key: 'captain_id'
    has_many  :users, dependent: :destroy

    validates :ground_name, presence:true 
    validates :team_name, presence:true 
    validates :captain_id, presence:true ,uniqueness: true
end


class User < ApplicationRecord       
      belongs_to :team,optional: true
end
```

This is my show view:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Team Name</th>
    <th>Ground Name</th>
    <th>Captain Name</th>
    <th>Manage</th>
  </tr>
  <% @team.each do |f| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= f.id  %></td>
    <td><%= f.team_name %></td>
    <td><%= f.ground_name %></td>
    <td><%= f.captain_id&.first_name %></td>
  </tr>
  <%end%>
</table>
```

This generates the error:

> undefined method `first_name' for 2:Integer

This is my database schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_02_19_090032) do

  create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "team_id"
    t.string "team_name"
    t.string "ground_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "captain_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "photo"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "team_id"
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["team_id"], name: "index_users_on_team_id"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The associated user should be available under the attribute `captain`. So your markup should look like this:

```
<td><%= f.captain&.first_name %></td>
```

Instead of `:has_to`, you should define a `:belongs_to` relation, so that the foreign key is defined in the team table:

```
belongs_to :captain, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :captain_id
```

If you do not have the captain_id column defined in your teams table, you have to create a migration and run it.

To create the migration:

rails g migration add_captain_id_to_teams

Now you have a new migration file in db/migrate, something like `db/migrate/<timestamp>_add_captain_id_to_teams.rb`

Open this file and edit it to look like this:

```
class AddCaptainIdToTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :teams, :captain_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Now run this command to create the column:

bundle exec rake db:migrate

Now you can assign the captain id and save it in the database.

Comment: Or <td><%= f.captain&.first_name %></td> if you're not sure if captain is set.

Comment: @Smek thx! I updated the answer. This makes it consistent with the question.

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.captain_id: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."captain_id" = ? LIMIT ?  it gave me this error

Comment: @gangothri I extended my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Following can solve issue,

```
<td><%= f.captain&.first_name %></td>
```

but following can also you can use,

```
<td><%= f.captain.first_name %></td>
```

No need to add `optional: true`, remove it & remove following from `team.rb`

```
validates :captain_id, presence:true ,uniqueness: true
```

because we removed `optional: true`

In `user.rb`, correction is needed,

```
belongs_to :team, optional: true, foreign_key: :captain_id
```

Comment: i cant create user, if i remove optional: true. it validates team by default. and captain for each team should be unique, uniqueness aslo needed

Comment: apply uniqueness validation only remove presence validation

Comment: i removed presence vvalidation and got this error. SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.captain_id: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."captain_id" = ? LIMIT ?

Comment: @gangothri Your table schema is missing `captain_id` column please check

Comment: i added my schema @ray